# Rounding DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have DateTime data in a MS SQL database with the following format:

`2020-05-07 22:35:00`

I am trying to create a query that only captures data from the last 24 hours of operations. However, our operations KPIs are measured from 6AM-6AM. I would like to round the date based on time. Anything before 6AM will be counted as the day before.

```
2020-05-07 05:45:00 -> 2020-05-06 (Before 6AM)
2020-05-07 06:30:00 -> 2020-05-07 (After 6AM)
```

So far I have been successful in pulling the previous days activity, but am struggling to shift the timeframe to round down anything before 6AM

```
SELECT 
      end_date 
FROM data sint
WHERE sint.end_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND sint.end_date < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add six hours to the current date (without the time) for the comparison:

```
where int.end_date < dateadd(hour, 6, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) and
      int.end_date >= dateadd(hour, 6 - 24, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
```

Note that the conversion to `date` removes the time component.

Comment: I appreciate the response! However, when i tried this its giving me the following error       
 "The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date."

Comment: @JimFisher . . . Fixed.  That is something I always do . . . SQL Server converts a *string* to `datetime` (`select dateadd(hour, 1, '2020-05-08')`) but it won't convert a `date` to `datetime` (`select dateadd(hour, 1, convert(date, '2020-05-08'))`).  Baffling and inconsistent in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

first get the time part. Compare the time part with 6AM and run your expression.

In below code the time part is compared with the date '1900-01-01 06:00:00' which is 6AM in default date format.

```
select 
  case when cast(date as time(0)) < '1900-01-01 06:00:00' 
       then cast(date - 1 as date) 
            else cast(date as date) 
  end as newdate
  from temp_date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is definitely a different way of looking at the problem that also works, converting it to a new date. I ended up using this as well as Gordon's answer for my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same as Gordon only the opposite side.

I would subtract 6 hours from end_date and then compare.

```
where convert(date, dateadd(hour, -6, int.end_date)) = convert(date, getdate())
```

Though this method might not work well if you're actually using `getdate()`.  It will return nothing if it is ran between midnight and 6 am (unless you have future dates).